# custom fold expression to fold functions

Tags: regular-expression, folding

I would like to create a custom fold expression for functions of the form

```
x <- function(a,b,c) {
  ...
  ... body
  ...
}
```

where the lines starting from function(...) until the closing brace are to have the same fold level.
Yet, I do not want code in other braces to be folded (such as if blocks).

How can I do this?

(For those who are wondering, this is r syntax)

For the start of the function, I have tried

```
function! FoldExpr(lnum) 
  let thisline = getline(a:lnum)
  if thisline =~ '[^#].*function(.*)\s*{'
    return 'a1'
  elseif "... condition to check end of function ...
    " ...
  endif
endfunction
```

However, I am unsure how to check if a line is the last line of the function.
I am able to check if the line contains a closing `}`. But how can I tell if it is the closing brace of the function?

(BTW, I am using a fold expression instead of `foldmethod=syntax` as I would like to fold other objects as well, not just functions)

Comment: Note that your VimScript isn't valid at all. There are no curly braces in VimScript; the end of a function is denoted with `endfunction`. You're also missing an `endif`. The [Nvim-R plugin](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) already seems to do what you want, so you may be better off using that (or lifting the relevant parts from it)?

Comment: @MartinTournoij Thanks, I've corrected the mistakes in the VimScript.